# Require packages in my script

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I have a python script that makes use of the requests library.
I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to go about displaying packages required to run my script other than exception handling on the import statements. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: You could add a requirements.txt file, but almost everybody that has python already has requests installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The packages required to run any python script mention in top of the script
by `import moduleName`.

you can get a list of installed packages in your python by this:

```
import pip
installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
for pack in installed_packages:
    print pack
```

Use this in top of your code this will install required modules if missing from python.

```
try:
    import yourModule
except ImportError:
    # Do installation process here
    # pip install module ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You have some alternatives:

1) You can write a README with the instructions to run your script;

2) You can develop a Makefile to automate the setup;

3) You can write a requirements.txt with the dependencies and versions;

4) You can write the setup.py file using [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/);

5) Or you can catch de exception ImportModule, and do a download of dependencies.